# Confirmation dialog box only appears when using the ISE

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We use one of the AD extension attributes to tag a group with a users ID as the "owner" of that group.  Only the owners can request changes/additions etc to the group.

I have a fairly lengthy PowerShell script that works well.  It asks for a users logon name in a dialog box, polls for groups they're in, displays that list in another dialog box, and when I select a group from that list, it'll confirm if the user is an owner of that group.   The last dialog box gives the YES or NO answer, and DOES WORK when I'm running the script via the ISE, but does not display that final answer if I'm just running the script via command line or use the 'run with powershell' option.

Here's the piece of code in question.  I'll dump the whole script if people think it's necessary to reference.

```
#Declares if the user is an owner of selected group or not.

if ($match -eq $False) {
    #write-host "The user $user IS NOT an owner of $group"
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("The user $user IS NOT an owner of $group")
}
else
{
    #write-host "The user $user DOES own $group"
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("The user $user DOES own $group")
}
```

The reason for this script is ultimately so users can self-serve some basic requests for group disposition.  Adding a new member, removing a member, even moving a group to another OU.   But the dialog box needs to appear, especially if the user in question doesn't own the group.   If they do, it would be a click-through to the next functions (which are not really written in a cohesive form yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`System.Windows.MessageBox` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of Windows Presentation Framework, and contained in the `PresentationFramework.dll` assembly.

Make sure you load it into your session before calling `MessageBox.Show()`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
# Now you can use [System.Windows.MessageBox]
```

The reason it works in ISE is likely that ISE itself is already a WPF application, and so the `PresentationFramework` assembly is already loaded into it's AppDomain

Comment: The ISE loads almost twice as many assemblies over just opening a PowerShell window. Strange but true...

Comment: In all fairness, it doesn't just need to import the S.M.A API and interface with conhost, it has to emulate conhost + implement a full dev environment. Not that strange that it has many more referenced assemblies when you think about it

Comment: Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

That did it!   I was hoping it was something simple like this!   Thank you!

Comment: @RichJ You're most welcome. If my answer solves your problem, please mark it "accepted" by clicking the grey checkmark on the left